# \includemedia won't play video

Tags: linux, media9

the code seems to be correct, with compilation no error appears.
The code is

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Title}

\includemedia[
width=\paperwidth,height=0.7\linewidth,
activate=pageopen,
flashvars={movie.mp4 &autoPlay=true}
]{}{movie.mp4}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

He won't play the video and with no error I don't know what to do. Please anyone has an idea? I use adobe reader 9.4.2.

Comment: Also my videos have indeed format mp4 with H.264 compression.

Comment: With adobe this error appears: `A 3D data parsing error has occurred.` Any ideas please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Would you please add some information about your operating system and TeX distribution and turn the code snippet into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)

Comment: I'm not really sure that `media9` works with the very outdated TeX Live 2009/Debian

Comment: How can I update it?

Comment: See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)

Comment: Updating does not help. Even cor
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian
I get this error too!

Comment: Reader version (9.4.2) is not useable (for media playback on Linux). And the code in your question has errors.

Answer (score 5):

The code is *not* correct. Playback of a video file (`movie.mp4`) needs a Flash-based media player to be included as the last argument of `\includemedia`. The video file itself must be embedded as a resource file and be made known to the media player by means of a media player specific Flash variable.

Adobe Reader on Linux has support for Flash and media playback up to version 9.4.1. It was dropped thereafter. The built-in Flash player of AR-9.4.1 supports Flash content up to Flash version 9. However, the media players shipping with `media9` require Flash Player 10.

[player_flv_maxi.swf](http://flv-player.net/medias/player_flv_maxi.swf) is Flash Player 9 compatible and can be used with `media9` and AR-9.4.1 on Linux. Its FlashVars for configuration are documented [here](http://flv-player.net/players/maxi/documentation). The most important FlashVar is the one for setting the video source. Here it is called `flv=...`.

AR-9.4.1 for Linux can be downloaded from Adobes [FTP server](ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.4.1/).

Here is your adapted code example that should work:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}

\includemedia[
  width=\paperwidth,
  height=0.7\linewidth,
  activate=pageopen,
  addresource=movie.mp4,
  flashvars={flv=movie.mp4&autoplay=1}
]{}{player_flv_maxi.swf}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your adapted code does not work either. It still leads to the same 3D parsing error. I run xubuntu 12.04, fully patched, with pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian), and the latest version of beamer. Something must be fundamentally wrong here...

Comment: @bothide: What is wrong, is the Reader version you are using. Read my answer carefully.

Comment: @AlexG I am told that I need expl3.sty to run this program.  (I also needed media9.sty, but I found it online). Do I need anything else?  How do I get the expl3.sty?

Comment: @JG: I suggest you install TeXLive-2012. It provides everything you need.

Answer (score 2):

Answer 1 gets me a bit further on with this problem but there are a few more wrinkles to get ironed out.

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and have updated texlive to 2012.20120611-3~ubuntu12.04.1 .

The CTAN media9.pdf specifies Adobe Reader, version greater or equal to 9 so I was happy to be on version 9.5 . Having removed 9.5 and downloaded 9.4.1 and run the corrected version of the code provided above by Alex I have a satisfactorily compiled tex document that produces a pdf beamer slide.

The video pane in the slide is blank with a "Buffering 0%" message and a very nice looking slider at the bottom of the pane. This is all to do with not having the H264 codec installed to do your .avi -> .mp4 encoding. Have a look in Synaptic package manager for h264enc and install it. I used Transmaggedon as a gui front end and specified Output format: MPEG4  and for Choose video codec: H264. Alternatively if you want loads of options run h264enc from the terminal as it is a shell script.

This gives an .mp4 file that plays in the video pane of Alex's example code.

In summary:
1. latest texlive installation
2. Adobe Reader 9.4.1
3. install h264enc

Comment: This looks more like a comment to AlexG's answer than an answer. It might be converted to a comment. It would be great if you would extend this to a solution, once that you found it.