# How to embed videos in pdf with ConTeXt?

Tags: pdf, context, animations, embedding

I have heard that it is possible to embed videos with ConTeXt in tex-files and in the resulting pdf-file. Hans Hagen wrote very briefly about videos in his manual, but there is no Minexample. I could not find anything about videos in the wiki.

Answer (score 8):

The following example defines `\embedvideo`. It uses the same media embedding method as the `media9` LaTeX package. Video files in the ***MP4/H264*** and ***FLV*** formats are played back within the video player component [VPlayer.swf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/players/VPlayer.swf) shipping with `media9`.

See the [media9 manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/media9.pdf) on how to configure `VPlayer` via FlashVars, which are passed as the 3rd argument of `\embedvideo`.

The video player can be controlled by left mouse button press (pause) and release (play/resume), via the context menu accessed by right mouse button click and via the keyboard (see context menu for keys).

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \embedvideo{<width>}{<height>}{<flashvars>}{<video file (MP4+H264 or FLV)>}
% flashvars documented in `texdoc media9`,  page 19
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\protected\def\pdfobj{\pdfextension obj }
\def\pdflastobj{\numexpr\pdffeedback lastobj\relax}
\protected\def\pdfannot{\pdfextension annot }
\let\pdfxform\saveboxresource
\let\pdflastxform\lastsavedboxresourceindex
\define[4]\embedvideo{%
  \ifdefined\vplayer\else%
    \immediate\pdfobj stream file {VPlayer.swf}%
    \immediate\pdfobj{<<
      /Type/Filespec/F (VPlayer.swf)/UF (VPlayer.swf)
      /EF <</F \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R>>
    >>}%
    \edef\vplayer{\the\pdflastobj}%
  \fi%
  %
  \immediate\pdfobj stream file {#4}%
  \immediate\pdfobj{<<
    /Type/Filespec/F (#4)/UF (#4)
    /EF <</F \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R>>
  >>}%
  \edef\video{\the\pdflastobj}%
  %
  \immediate\pdfobj{<<
    /Type/RichMediaInstance/Subtype/Video
    /Asset \vplayer\space 0 R
    /Params <</Binding/Foreground/FlashVars (source=#4&#3)>>
  >>}%
  %
  \immediate\pdfobj{<<
    /Type/RichMediaConfiguration/Subtype/Video
    /Instances [\the\pdflastobj\space 0 R]
  >>}%
  %
  \immediate\pdfobj{<<
    /Type/RichMediaContent
    /Assets <<
      /Names [(VPlayer.swf) \vplayer\space 0 R (#4) \video\space 0 R]
    >>
    /Configurations [\the\pdflastobj\space 0 R]
  >>}%
  \edef\rmcontent{\the\pdflastobj}%
  %
  \pdfobj{<<
    /Activation <<
      /Condition/PO
      /Presentation <<
        /Transparent true
        /Style/Embedded
        /PassContextClick true
      >>
    >>
    /Deactivation <</Condition/PC>>
  >>}%
  %
  \setbox0=\vbox to #2 {\vss\hbox to #1{\tt #4\hss}\vss}%
  \immediate\pdfxform 0%
  %
  \pdfannot width #1 height #2 depth 0pt {
    /Subtype/RichMedia
    /BS <</W 0/S/S>>
    /Contents (embedded video file:#4)
    /NM (rma:#4)
    /AP <</N \the\pdflastxform\space 0 R>>
    /RichMediaSettings \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R
    /RichMediaContent \rmcontent\space 0 R
  }%
  \hbox to #1 {\vbox to #2 {}\hss}%
}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\starttext
\ConTeXt{} video  example:

top

left\embedvideo{4cm}{3cm}{autoPlay=true&loop=true}{random.mp4}right

bottom
\stoptext
```

Comment: Is this also supposed to work on Linux? I downloaded `VPlayer.swf` and `random.mp4` from `media9` directory and placed them in the current directory, and compiled your sample file. When I open it in acroread 9.5.1 (Linux 32 bit), I get a pop-up box: "A 3D data parsing error has occured".

Comment: [This LaTeX question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60160/includemedia-wont-play-video) seems to suggest that AR9.5 does not include a Flash Player. I would need to downgrade AR to AR9.4.1 AND install player_flv_maxi. It might be simpler to just try to install AR using wine :(

Comment: @Aditya: Exactly...

Comment: @Aditya: If you have a full TeXLive installation (with media9) and if you are using VPlayer, you don't need to download it to your current dir.

Comment: Thanks for this. I can confirm that this method works with Adobe Acrobat on MacOS. It will be nice to wrap this around a more ConTeXt-ish interface.

Comment: @Aditya: I am not familiar with ConTeXt, but isn't the use of `\define` the right way to write new commands in ConTeXt?

Comment: `\deine` is okay. I meant that instead of using `\embedvideo{width}{height}{extras}{filename}` use `\embedvideo[filename][width=..., height=..., extras=...]`. I'll write the boilerplate code and then post the result here.

Comment: @Aditya : But then, `width=..., height=..., extras=...` would look like optional settings. However, `width` and `height` are needed to correctly size the widget and therefore should be mandatory arguments. How does ConTeXt distinguish between mandatory and optional arguments? Could you give me some pointer to where this is documented and how to define new commands?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I'll write a wrapper for this soon.

Answer (score 7):

```
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\setupinteraction[state=start]
\starttext
\externalfigure[clip.mov][height=2cm, width=2cm, preview=yes]
\stoptext
```

only .mov is supported. This is the same code you'd use to typeset an image.